# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION depends on the size of the data

Tags: c

I'm at exercise 17 of Learn C the hard way,which require building a database and store it in a FILE.I have initialized a database as expected, but when I increased the number of rows (particularly over the threshold of 100) in the database, it returned 
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=0010040132C.

I used GDB to search for the error, and here's the result.

> Thread 1 "ex17" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x000000010040132c in Database_create (conn=0x600049490, max_data=12, >max_rows=200) at ex17_1.c:87
>   87                   *(conn->db->rows +i*sizeof(struct Address)) =addr;

Here's the code I have used.

```
struct Address{
int id;
int set;
char *name;
char *email;
};
struct Database{
int MAX_ROWS;
int MAX_DATA;
struct Address *rows;
};
struct Connection{
FILE *file;
struct Database *db;
};
void Database_create(struct Connection *conn,int max_data,int max_rows){
conn->db->MAX_DATA =max_data;
conn->db->MAX_ROWS = max_rows;
conn->db->rows =malloc(max_rows*sizeof(struct Address));
for(int i=0;i<max_rows;i++){
    struct Address addr = {.id =i,.set = 0};
    *(conn->db->rows +i*sizeof(struct Address)) =addr;
}
```

}

I have done some research and I think that STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION occurs when
you access a part of memory you are not supposed to. But I have not seen the error in my code yet.
Can someone check what is the possible reason here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]  and note which line of code is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on this line

```
 +i*sizeof(struct Address)
```

The compiler already multiplies by the size when adding to pointers so don't do it again.  You want only

```
+i
```

Comment: Indeed, although the pointer arithmetic form is perfectly valid, it would be more idiomatic to write the statement from which that is drawn as `conn->db->rows[i] =addr;`, which sidesteps the whole issue.

Comment: you mean +i is enough?

Comment: @VanTeoLe: Yup.

Comment: I don't know how, but it did work now. So I think that the problem is when i use +i*(sizeof(struct Address)) ,it is multiplied by square of sizeof() and exceed the memory malloc() give me right?